# Samba file sharing cache

Tags: linux, cache, file-sharing, samba4, branchcache

Does Samba have any option for file caching over WAN (connected via VPN)?
I've looked into WAN optimization, but I want something simple to setup.

Setup:

Linux File Server(Main Office)====WAN====Linux Server(Branch)===Clients O/S (Branch)

Goal:  When Client O/S (Branch) makes a file request(open/download) from Linux File Server(Main Office), its cache a copy to the Linux Server(Branch). Every time the Client O/S (Branch) makes a file request, it looks at the Client O/S (Branch) 1st.

Microsoft has this technology(Branch Cache), but Windows is not an option for us. What options are there for Linux?

Answer (score 1):

As I am familiar with samba and the way it works, I don't think there's such an option.